# MvvmCross binding + Android EventHandler

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a situation in MvvmCross Android where I have a SeekBar's position bound to a property in the view model. The property can be updated by sliding the seek bar or by an external api interaction taking place over web sockets. If the user is currently sliding the seek bar, I don't want the external api to be able to update the property and cause the seek bar to visibly jump around.

I'm trying to do this by setting an IsDimming property when the user starts sliding and stops sliding. However as soon as I assign these native EventHandlers, the set {} part of my property is no longer hit when you drag the seek bar.

Binding in the XML view:

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:max="100"
    local:MvxBind="Progress DimmerPosition" />
```

Properties in the view model:

```
public bool IsDimming { get; set; }

private float _dimmerPosition;
public float DimmerPosition {
    get {
        return _dimmerPosition;
    }
    set { // This isn't hit when I have assigned native event handlers
        _dimmerPosition = value;
        _eventService.SendLightingState (UUIDAction, Number, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged (() => DimmerPosition);
    }
}
```

My native Android event handlers in the view's code behind:

```
var slider = FindViewById<SeekBar> (Resource.Id.seekBar);
slider.StartTrackingTouch += (object sender, SeekBar.StartTrackingTouchEventArgs e) => {
    ViewModel.IsDimming = true;
};

slider.StopTrackingTouch += (object sender, SeekBar.StopTrackingTouchEventArgs e) => {
    ViewModel.IsDimming = false;
};
```

Is there any way I can have the binding AND use the event handlers? Worth noting that the binding continues to work ok in iOS when I assign to the TouchDown and TouchUpInside event handlers.

Many thanks

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is caused by both the MvvmCross binding and the internal Xamarin event handling both using `SeekbarListener`'s - while Java only allows one of them to work at a time.

In MvvmCross's case, this listener is at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxSeekBarProgressTargetBinging.cs#L41

One way around this for your case is: you could replace MvvmCross's binding with a custom binding which uses a `ProgressChanged` event handler instead of a listener. To do this:

1. Copy the code from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxSeekBarProgressTargetBinging.cs into your own project and then rename it to `MySeekBarProgressTargetBinding`
2. Change the `SubscribeToEvents` code to use an event delegate subscription instead of the listener. Also, be sure to unsubscribe in `Dispose` too.
3. Change your `Setup` code to register `MySeekBarProgressTargetBinding` for "Progress" (as long as you do this after the core `Mvx` one, then I think your one will "win")

   ```
   registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(typeof(MySeekBarProgressTargetBinding), typeof(SeekBar),
                                               "Progress");
   ```

I think that should work....

Extra bonus points are also available if you push some changes back to Mvx that address this for everyone (and that fix the name from `Binging` to `Binding` too). I believe that when that bit of Mvx was written, then the event handlers either weren't available or weren't working (that's why it used a custom listener).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Stuart. I had thought it was unlikely that the OnStartTrackingTouch and OnStopTrackingTouch were used in the binding code and indeed I can see they are not. But assigning to them must cause the entire SeekBarChangeListener to be replaced.

I think I can probably convert this binding to use event handlers as you suggest and would be happy to contribute it back to the project.